# A picture read by opencv get Nonetype, but use PIL I can have the correct image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

[image]

I tried to read this picture with cv2:

```
>>> im = cv2.imread('name.jpg')
>>> im is None
True
```

but if I read it using the PIL, I got the correct image:

```
im = Image.open('name.jpg')
im.show('dddd')
```

I can see the image showed correctly.
What is the problem from, and how could I solve it ?

Comment: `'name.jpg'` is in the same folder of your script?

Comment: You 'name.jpg' is a GIF file, not a JPEG file. `opencv` does not support GIF files.